# OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper failed to change locale for db

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I'm using OrmLiteSqlite framework for my andorid app, before I used directly SQLiteOpenHelper to mange my interaction with SqliteDB.
I use a preloaded database and with previous version of my code (with SQLiteOpenHelper) all works ok.
Now I would use this framework but when I try to load my database it seems not loaded and when I restart my app I've an error about localization into `android_meta` table.
I can't believe this framework has a bug! I've tried to create a database with out preloaded data following this [tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-ormlite-with-sqlite-database-tutorial/) but my app still crash for the same reason.
There is any way to prevent this error?